# crear un if que al presionar un botón haga una función de filtro

Tags: botón

aver si me pueden ayudar ,  estoy creando un filtro, asta ahora lo e logrado con la etiqueta option, y un boton submit pero quiero hacerlo sin el boton submi, como un if que al precionar me filtre la categoria...

ejemplo,

```
            $pelis="SELECT DISTINCT  genero FROM peliculas ";
            $respelis=$conexion->query($pelis);
            $resgenero=$conexion->query($pelis);
            ?>
            <select name="genero" >
                <option value="generos" disabled=""  class="option"> <?php echo('generos') ?></option>
                <?php
                     while ($registrogeneros = $resgenero->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
                    {
                        echo '<option value="'.$registrogeneros['genero'].'" class="option">'.$registrogeneros['genero'].'</option>';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <button name="buscar" type="submit" class="button">Buscar</button>
              </form>
```

esta es la vista..

```
    <?php 

    @$genero=$_POST['genero'];
     $query= "SELECT * FROM peliculas   WHERE genero ='$genero'"; 
     $resultado=$conexion->query($query);
     while($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
     ?>
        <table class="contenedor-pelicula">
        <td><label for=""><span >titulo:</span><?php echo $row['id']; ?>
        <?php echo $row['titulo']; ?> </label></td>
         </tr><tr>
        <td><label for=""><span >genero:</span><?php echo $row['genero']; ?> </label>
        <label for=""><span class="year">year:</span><?php echo $row['year']; ?> </td></label>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>
        <label for=""><span class="year">tipo:</span><?php echo $row['tipo']; ?> </label></td>
        </tr>

        </table>

     <?php 
        }
      ?>
   </tbody>
```

le agradezco la ayuda si no me entienden porfavor me dicen para explicar mejor ..

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner el evento onchange en select para evitar el boton:

```
$pelis="SELECT DISTINCT  genero FROM peliculas ";
        $respelis=$conexion->query($pelis);
        $resgenero=$conexion->query($pelis);
        ?>
        <select name="genero" onchange="buscar()">
            <option value="generos" disabled=""  class="option"> <?php echo('generos') ?></option>
            <?php
                 while ($registrogeneros = $resgenero->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
                {
                    echo '<option value="'.$registrogeneros['genero'].'" class="option">'.$registrogeneros['genero'].'</option>';
                }
            ?>
        </select>
          </form>
     <script>
         function buscar(){
             document.getElementById("id_de_tu_formulario").submit();
         }
     </script>
```

En el código javascript donde pone id_de_tu_formulario, pon el id que hayas asignado a tu etiqueta , deberia de funcionarte.

Comment: A que te refieres con cambiar el valor de 'b'? es decir, es posible añadir un if pero no sé la condición que deseas hacer para ejecutar el código. Un saludo.